# Meromorphic Continuation of Intertwining Operator Identities for K-finite vectors

Tags: representation-theory

I have a question about a "well-known result" about intertwining operators. I will restrict myself to $\text{SL}_2$ for simplicity.  Let

$$w = \left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right), \hspace{.25cm} n_x = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1&x\\0&1\end{array}\right),  \hspace{.25cm} k_\theta = \left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\ \sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{array}\right).$$

Let $K$ denote the group generated by $k_\theta$.  Consider the following space

$$I_\lambda = \left\{f \in C^\infty(\text{SL}_2): f\left(g \left( \begin{array}{cc}u&0\\*&u^{-1}\end{array}\right)\right) = |u|^{-(\lambda-1)} f(g) \right\}$$

where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, $u \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ and $g \in \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$. $\text{SL}_2$ acts on $I_\lambda$ by the left regular representation. The intertwining operator $J_{\lambda}:I_{-\lambda} \to I_{\lambda}$ is defined by

$$(J_\lambda f)(g) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(g w n_x) \, dx$$

where $f \in I_{-\lambda}$,   The integral defining $J_\lambda$ only converges for $\Re(\lambda)>0$, but has meromorphic continuation to $\mathbb{C}$. More precisely, this means that when we fix $f \in C^\infty(K)$, which we can identify with an element of $I_{\lambda}$, we have that the function

$$\lambda \mapsto J_\lambda f$$

is a meromorphic function from $\mathbb{C}$ to the Frechet space $C^\infty(K)$ (I think).

Consider $q_{\lambda} \in I_{\lambda}$ such that $q_\lambda(k_\theta) = 1$ (a simple example of a $K$-finite vector).  It is straightforward to compute that $J_{\lambda} q_{-\lambda} = G(\lambda) q_\lambda$ for $\Re(\lambda)>0$ for some function $G(\lambda)$.  One can show that $G(\lambda)$ has meromorphic continuation to $\mathbb{C}$. I would like to know if

$$J_{\lambda} q_{-\lambda} = G(\lambda) q_\lambda$$

for all $\lambda$ at which $G(\lambda)$ is defined.  I've been told that this is a "well-known result", but I have had trouble finding a reference for it or proving it myself.